# How to guess the dependence of decay rate on mass for this process?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Here is part of the Lagrangian I'm considering:
$$
L_{int} = -\frac{1}{3}\lambda\phi^3-g\phi\bar\Psi\chi-g\phi\bar\chi\Psi
$$
I'm interested in two decay processes drawn below (assume $\Psi$ particle has mass $M$, and $\phi$ and $\chi$ have mass $m$, $M>2m$):
[image]
I have found the decay width for $(a)$ is
$$
\frac{g^2}{16\pi}\sqrt{M^2-4m^2}\frac{M+2m}{M}
$$
The question is without doing a detailed calculation, can we tell how the decay width depends on $m$ in the region $M\simeq 3m$ for the process $(b)$.

I don't know how to make a sensible guess. I assume maybe there will be some dependence on the factor $\sqrt{M^2-9m^2}$ ( as there is a $3m$)?

Comment: Not a bad guess. The rest of the width, corresponding to the square of the matrix element might be more complicated, also involving an extra factor of $\lambda^2$...

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Thanks, should the extra factor be $\lambda$ instead (because there is one $\phi^3$ vertex)?

Comment: λ in the amplitude, which you square in the width; look at what happens to *g*.